# GoCD Copy dist folder to host system

Tags: angular, docker, pipeline, go-cd

I have a GoCD instance running inside a docker container. I want to build an angular2 project by angular-cli through the pipeline of GoCD. This works well, but I need to copy the built dist folder from the docker container to "/var/www/html/" folder on the **host** system.

Im very new to GoCD and docker. Can anyone help me?

Edit: One more questions is: where is the dist folder located after build finished?

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution would be to bind mount local `/var/www/html` somewhere inside of your container and copy those files to that mounted directory which is now accessible from your container.

How you can create the bind mount depends on how you are launching your container (docker cli or docker-compose...)

if you are using docker cli, you can use `-v` switch

```
docker run -v /var/www/html:/somwhere/in/your/container ...
```

example in `docker-compose`

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  name-of-your-service:
    image: name-of-your-image
    volumes:
       - /var/www/html:/somwhere/in/your/container 
    ...
```

Comment: I will try this, sounds good. One more questions is: where is the dist folder located after build finished?

Comment: Sorry, I am not that familiar with GoCD and I think that angular by default creates dist in the root of the project (but this is configurable so it depends on how you set it up, but this should be easily obtainable information, either by going through the relevant docs or by inspecting the container itself.

Comment: this helps me i could mount the directory but I dont know where the dist folder which comes out of the dist directory is located so I can copy it... does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

Follow following steps to copy a file from an image.

1. Create a dummy container 
   `docker create -ti --name "container_name" "docker_iamge_from_which_you_want_to_copy_file" bash`
   docker_iamge_from_which_you_want_to_copy_file is your image name.
2. copy file from dummy continer to your local path 
   docker cp "container_name":"path_in_image" "local_path"

in your case local_path is /var/www/html/ and path_in_image is your dist location inside your container.